# Regex to match variations of characters

Tags: regex, char, character

So people are using variations of characters like this:
(there are like 100s of these, lol)
⌀⟴øoΘθ0ºööó֎
to spam racist/disallowed things.

I use regex to counter these things, but there's no way I can counter all these different variations.

Is there anything I can do?

Maybe a premade list of these characters variations, or some other way?

Comment: Please be more specific. What have you already tried, please provide an example and also explain which part of your solution is not returning the expected results. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: Dont understand what could possibly be unclear here.. Here's something I've used, `[mMΜμʍṁɱℳ₥ₘ]` to some variations, but it's really of no help since since are like a thousands of those greek or whatever variations.

Comment: Because these are special characters you should use a regex on the ascii code for the characters in the given string. If you are lucky then the special characters you want to ignore will be next to each other in a given ascii code range, you can then just filter out the range you want to ignore. See here: http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/

Comment: Could you just filter out all special characters - Like only allow plain letters, numbers and a few punctuation marks? It would interfere with non-English speakers though.

Comment: This is for my TeamSpeak bot. The problem persists especially in the TeamSpeak nicknames. So I can't, and wouldn't really even want to, disallow special chars.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of blacklisting, you could use whitelists to only allow characters such as those between a-z, A-Z and 0-9, as well as special characters such as ,.^-?! `([a-zA-Z0-9.,;!*?\-^]+)`.

See an example of matches at: http://rubular.com/r/sUiLj2e1R1.